# Show/Hide HTML Elements from a Input Select option in Blazor Server app

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using the following Javascript function to show elements when a button is triggered.

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('myDIV').style.display = "block"; }
```

I call this function on a button with

```
@onclick=showDiv
```

I would like to do the same but on an InputSelect List. I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
<label>Number of engines:</label>
<InputSelect style="width: 25%" @bind-Value="model.NumberofEngines" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-- Select the number of engines --</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option @onclick=ShowDiv>2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
</InputSelect>
```

The idea is a calculator that calculates ship emissions and the user should choose the number of engines the ship has and the app should show the required inputs.

Comment: To clarify: You want to show a different set of options based on the value chosen in the `<InputSelect ...`  If they click on 2 engines a different "2 engines" options would appear below the input select?

Comment: Yes. For example, if he chooses 3 engines then three textboxes for
Engine 1 Speed, 
Engine 2 speed 
Engine 3 speed, 
and three other textboxes for
Engine 1 manufacture,
 Engine 2 manufacture
 Engine 3 manufacture 
et cetera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple css style to show hide given div on value in model.NumberofEngines

```
<div style="display: @(model.NumberofEngines == "1"  ? "block" : "none");">
    ONE
</div>
```

Here is complete code

```
<EditForm>
    <label>Number of engines:</label>
    <InputSelect style="width: 25%" @bind-Value="model.NumberofEngines" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-- Select the number of engines --</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
    </InputSelect>
</EditForm>


<div style="display: @(model.NumberofEngines == "1"  ? "block" : "none");">
    ONE
</div>


<div style="display: @(model.NumberofEngines == "2"  ? "block" : "none");">
    TWO
</div>

<div style="display: @(model.NumberofEngines == "3"  ? "block" : "none");">
    THREE
</div>

<div style="display: @(model.NumberofEngines == "4"  ? "block" : "none");">
    FOUR
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use css class also to show hide given div

Comment: Thank you for your help! I get the following error: InvalidOperationException: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputSelect`1[System.String] requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext. For example, you can use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputSelect`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] inside an EditForm.

I have the Numberofengines as string

Comment: My bad, I have updated my answer, please try it and your model should have this property as string   NumberofEngines

Comment: works perfectly. Something that will save me some time: What if I want with Select:1 Display:1 Select 2:Display number 1 and 2 Select 3 Display: 1 and 2 and 3 Select 4 Display:1 and 2 and 3 and 4

Comment: you can always mix conditions like this, or can design your own logic to show hide divs
<div style="display: @(model.NumberofEngines == "1" || model.NumberofEngines == "2" || model.NumberofEngines == "3"  || model.NumberofEngines == "4" ? "block" : "none");">
    ONE
</div>

Answer (score 4):

I think you should Use onchange
Test this code:

```js
function onChangeDiv(divId, element)
{
    document.getElementById(divId).style.display = element.value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<select name="frm_select" onchange="onChangeDiv('result', this)">
   <option value="1">show</option>
   <option value="0">hidden</option>
</select>
<div id="result">This is a div</div>
```

Comment: It doesnt work with InputSelect. Only with Select. How do I have multiple options to show? 4 options and each one showing different div?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers work sure.

From a coding perspective Blazor rendors the dom it does not manipulate the dom.

The problems with the javascript/css aproach *in a blazor app* are:

- You have to set up the javascript.
- You render stuff into the dom that does not need to be there. This has runtime costs in both Blazor and the Browser. If the "Configurations" use components or have blazor logic they are **all** going to be instanced/bindings configured ect. even if "hidden".

A **Blazor** C# way to do this is:

```
@page "/"
@using static Index.CarEngines

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm Model=@model >
    <InputSelect @bind-Value=model.Engines >
        <option value=@One >One</option>
        <option value=@Two >Two</option>
        <option value=@Three >Three</option>
        <option value=@Four >Four</option>
    </InputSelect>
</EditForm>

@switch (model.Engines)
{
    case One:
        <div>One Engine Configuration</div>
        break;
    case Two:
        <div>Two Engine Configuration</div>
        break;
    case Three:
        <div>Three Engine Configuration</div>
        break;
    case Four:
        <div>Four Engine Configuration</div>
        break;
}
@code {

    SomeModel model = new();

    public class SomeModel 
    {
        public CarEngines Engines { get; set; } = One;
    }

    public enum CarEngines
    {
        One = 1,
        Two,
        Three,
        Four
    }
}
```

**Run this and compare what is in the dom...**

Obviously the configuration html inside each case block will add complexity, break these out into separate blazor components. This design will make that a lot simpler as well.